# I have a list of date of birth. I want to convert it by age group. i.e: group-1: age 0 - 15, group 2: age 15 -20 etc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
 var allBirthdate = await _Repository.GetAll().Where(x => x.DateOfBirth.HasValue).
                Select(x => x.DateOfBirth.Value).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=3HqnBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=linq+group+by+age+group&source=bl&ots=7917WODqGg&sig=ACfU3U1qvtZ6LR1dFsu4Bcfuk8e_COfudg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCpfOT087oAhUCyKYKHSeGB0MQ6AEwBXoECAwQLw#v=onepage&q=linq%20group%20by%20age%20group&f=false

Comment: Create a function and group by these groups

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use groupby method, you can use following approach but it's a bit complicated and messy in your case. But this may be followed in some cases.

```
private static (List<Person> OlderPersons, List<Person> YoungerPersons) GroupByAgeV1(List<Person> people, DateTime refDate)
{
  var groupedDates = people.Where(x => x.DateOfBirth.HasValue).GroupBy(p => p.DateOfBirth >= refDate).ToList();

  var olderPersons = groupedDates.Where(g => g.Key == false)
                      .Select(g => g.ToList())
                      .ToList()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
  var youngerPersons = groupedDates.Where(g => g.Key == false)
                    .Select(g => g.ToList())
                    .ToList()
                      .FirstOrDefault();

  return (OlderPersons: olderPersons, YoungerPersons: youngerPersons);

}
```

This approach seems better and easier to read in your case

```
private static (List<Person> OlderPersons, List<Person> YoungerPersons) GroupByAgeV2(List<Person> people, DateTime refDate)
{
  var peopleHasBirtDate = people.Where(x => x.DateOfBirth.HasValue).ToList();

  var olderPersons = peopleHasBirtDate.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth >= refDate).ToList();
  var youngerPersons = peopleHasBirtDate.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth < refDate).ToList();

  return (OlderPersons: olderPersons, YoungerPersons: youngerPersons);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property (read-only) to your class, or write an extension to calculate the age group:

```
public int AgeGroup
{
    get
    {
        if (!DateOfBirth.HasValue)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Value.Year;
        return
            age <= 15 ? 1 :
            age <= 20 ? 2 :
            age <= 35 ? 3 :
            age <= 60 ? 4 : 5;
    }
}
```

Then, get a dictionary which has the age group id (1,2,3) as the key and a list of your class instances which fall in this age group as the value, like the following:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Person>> byAgeGroup = people
    .GroupBy(x => x.AgeGroup)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple console app that takes a similar approach as outlined by @Oguz Ozgul:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public int Age
            => (int) Math.Floor((DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - DateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365);

        public int AgeGroup
        {
            get
            {
                if (Age < 15) // [0,14]
                    return 1;
                if (Age < 20) // [15,19]
                    return 2;
                if (Age < 30) // [20,29]
                    return 3;
                if (Age < 40) // [30,39]
                    return 4;
                if (Age < 60) // [40, 59]
                    return 5;
                return 6; // 60+
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> _ageGroupRanges
            = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "0 to 14"},
                {2, "15 to 19"},
                {3, "20 to 29"},
                {4, "30 to 39"},
                {5, "40 to 59"},
                {6, "60+"}
            };

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person {Name = "Joe", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01)},
                new Person {Name = "Dan", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1982, 01, 01)},
                new Person {Name = "Laura", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01)},
                new Person {Name = "Beth", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01)}
            };
            var peopleGroupedByAge = people
                .GroupBy(p => p.AgeGroup)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key);

            foreach (var group in peopleGroupedByAge)
            {
                var ageGroup = group.Key;
                var ageGroupRange = _ageGroupRanges[ageGroup];
                var namesOfPeopleInGroup = string.Join(", ", group.Select(p => p.Name));
                Console.WriteLine($"Age group {ageGroup} ({ageGroupRange}): {namesOfPeopleInGroup}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The most important bits are the the `Age` and `AgeGroup` computed properties added on to the `Person` object.  Step through the code in a debugger and inspect there values - you'll see that they encapsulate the logic around calculating which age group someone falls into.

Finally we need to group our `Person` objects into groups depending on what their age group is.  We can achieve this by the `GroupBy` method:

```
var peopleGroupedByAge = people
    .GroupBy(p => p.AgeGroup)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```